# Problems with weasyprint installation on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, path, gtk, weasyprint

I am trying to install weasyprint, my set up is:

- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Python 3.8.2 32-bit

I followed the official installation guide https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#windows painstakingly:

- Step 1: Install Python - check
- Step 2: Update pip and setuptools packages - check
- Step 3: Install WeasyPrint - check
- Step 4: Install the GTK+ libraries - check

  Note: I installed the 32-bit version of GTK+ since my python is 32-bit (via MSYS2 for 64-bit windows)
  and appended `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin` to `PATH` under advanced system settings > environment variables > system variables > Path
- Step 5: Test-Run WeasyPrint

  Executing the command `python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf` i get the answer `C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/python.exe: No module named weasyprint`

  Also when I execute similar commands like `python -m pip install WeasyPrint`i get the answer `C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/python.exe: No module named pip`

I guess there seems to be a problem with how I added `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin` to my path variable, but I can't find out what exactly is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the 64 bit version of python. uninstall what you have and go to the window store and install 3.8 python 64bit. and verify that by terminal and typing python and the python console says 64bit not 32.